# Animate Background Color Opacity of a List from brighter to dim - jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, html-lists

## I'm trying to make my :

1. notification list highlighted
2. animate background color opacity from brighter to dim (from .8 --> .3) in 1 second.
3. blink text 3 times.

I did these :

## Please Note:

> hexToRgb(faHexColor, opacity=.5 ) = rgba(255,193,7,0.5)

I kept getting

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

If I did these:

```
    $('ul.nfTable').find('.operationalEventText').first()
    .css({ 'background-color': hexToRgb(faHexColor, opacity =.8 ) })
    .css({ 'background-color': hexToRgb(faHexColor, opacity =.3 ) })
    .animate({ border: '1px solid ' + hexToRgb(faHexColor, opacity =.3 ) }, 1000)
    .animate({ color: faHexColor }, 300).animate({ color: "white" }, 300)
    .animate({ color: faHexColor }, 300).animate({ color: "white" }, 300)
    .animate({ color: faHexColor }, 300).animate({ color: "white" }, 300);


    $('ul.nfTable').find('.operationalEventText').first().animate({'background-color': '#abcdef',
        'opacity': 0.3}, 100);
```

It's working, but my console, went crazy.

[image]

Comment: why not only `.5` instead of `opacity=.5`?

Comment: I leave that so I can quickly see what is that `.5` is. It's not the issue though. If I remove it, the animate bgColor still not show any effect still.

Comment: Not sure they are cascading as you expect. Maybe place further animations in the Callback for the Animate function? Please provide a complete example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value, except as noted below; most properties that are non-numeric cannot be animated using basic jQuery functionality (For example, `width`, `height`, or `left` can be animated but `background-color` cannot be, unless the jQuery.Color plugin is used).

Best to add the jQuery UI library to make changes to Background Color with Animation.

> jQuery UI bundles the jQuery Color plugins which provides color animations as well as many utility functions for working with colors.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".box").click(function() {
    $(".box").animate({
      backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 193, 7, 1.0)"
    }, 1000, function() {
      console.log("Animation completed.");
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: I noticed it's only working when I used the jQuery UI version - you shared. Why ? do they just added this recently ?

Comment: Can I also animate my border thickness from 3 px to 1 px ? 

https://pastebin.com/raw/8VechWNp

Comment: My UI base on your suggested codes : https://i.imgur.com/jkEEEI6.png